# Name of sci fi book about sexual energy

Tags: story-identification, novel

I’m trying to remember the title of a sci fi book I read maybe 8 years ago, but from memory it wasn’t contemporary.

The protagonist is a girl / young woman whose father genetically engineered her and she begins to get powers based on sexual feelings. The start of the book I’m pretty sure she’s living with her mother and they don’t know where her father is.

Comment: I haven't read it but it sounds like something Piers Anthony and that is not a good thing.